# Chartkick is not loading in heroku, but works in local

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, chartkick, uglifier

I created a new rails application and configured the chartkick , the chart is loading good in local. But its not loading when pushed to heroku.

Why its loading in development without any error and not loading in heroku? Any clues?

**Application.js**

```
//= require Chart.bundle
//= require chartkick
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'chartkick'
```

**Applicaion.html.erb**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Testp</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= csp_meta_tag %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</head>

<body>
<%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Test#index</h1>
<%= column_chart [['Sample1', 52.9], ['Sample2', 27.7], ['Sample3', 1.6]]%>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you get any error in the console? Are the assets are loaded?

Comment: @Pavan yes, have updated the error screenshot.

Comment: Looks like chartkick is not loaded. Check whether its respective asset files loaded properly or not

Comment: did you try to compile assets locally?

Comment: BTW try disable uglifer (or whatever you use to minify js). If it works the issue should be within naming

Comment: Hey @Nondv, disabling uglifier solved this issue.

Comment: Any idea why uglifier causing this issue? and any way to re enable uglifier so that it wont affect the charts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed out in comments, when facing issues like "`something` not defined" one should try to disable Uglifer (or any minification tool). Minification can break your code pretty often because it messes with variable names.

I don't have general solution for this issue (minification) but you can always google your specific case:
https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/issues/347

Comment: uglifier gem version 4.1.18 caused JS errors for me too, I chnaged mine to 3.0.4 and my problems were resolved